# How can I create a checkbox with adjustable order in Jenkins? Or is it possible to customize prediction in String parameter in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Requirement:

- I want to run multiple test cases in a single Jenkins job.
- All those test cases are run one by one on the same Node.
- User should be able to specify execution order of those test cases.

What I've tried

- I tried checkbox. But order of checkbox candiates are fixed. Uses can select which test case
  they want to run, but cannot adjust the order.
- I tried String parameter. I put the candidate test case names in "description" and users can
  copy and paste them into the input box, split by comma. But it seems to be crude. Is it
  possible to add some, for example cutomized Groovy code to control the prediction. Whenever
  a user types first letters of a test case after a comma, candidate test case names are
  listed in a drop down list?

Or, does Jenkins provide a "select add" and "select remove" box pair? For example a left select box lists all candidate, and user select one and double click, or click "add" button, then the item is added to the right select box. And if user select an item in right box and click "remove" button, the item moves back to the right select box.

No matter which method is used, I just want to impelement such "select and adjust order" feature. How can I do it?